# Explicitly defaulted default constructor is implicitly deleted because of unordered_map used with a struct as key

Tags: c++, unordered-map, default-constructor

I have the following Graph class:

```
class Graph {
private:
    struct Edge {
        string vertex1{}, vertex2{};
        int val{};

        Edge() = default;
        ~Edge() = default;
        explicit Edge(string v1, string v2, int value) : vertex1(std::move(v1)), vertex2(std::move(v2)), val(value) {};
        bool operator==(const Edge&) const;
    };

    unordered_map<Edge, Edge*> edges;

public:
    Graph() = default;
    ~Graph();
}
```

When I want to construct a Graph with the default constructor, it says `Explicitly defaulted default constructor of 'Graph' is implicitly deleted because field 'edges' has a deleted default constructor`. How should I change my code, to be able to use the default constructor of Graph?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Key* in an `unordered_map` needs to be hashable. Either by adding a specialization of the `std::hash` class template or by providing a hashing functor when creating the `unordered_map`.

You haven't shown that you've made a `std::hash<Edge>` specialization and you aren't creating the `unordered_map` with a functor to do the hashing which is why default construction fails.

To add a `std::hash<Edge>` specialization you could do this (if you make `Edge` public):

```
namespace std {

template<>
struct hash<Graph::Edge> {
    size_t operator()(const Graph::Edge& e) const {
        size_t hash_result;
        // calculate the hash result
        return hash_result;
    }
};

} // namespace std
```

If you'd like to keep `Edge` `private` it may be easier to use a functor. Here's an example in the form of a `struct` which makes the `unordered_map` default constructible:

```
class Graph {
private:
    struct Edge {
        // ...
    };

    // the hashing functor:
    struct edge_hasher {
        size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
            // an example implementation using boost::hash_combine
            // from <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>:
            std::hash<std::string> h;
            size_t hash_result = 0;
            boost::hash_combine(hash_result, h(e.vertex1));
            boost::hash_combine(hash_result, h(e.vertex2));
            boost::hash_combine(hash_result, std::hash<int>{}(e.val));
            return hash_result;
        }
    };

    std::unordered_map<Edge, Edge*, edge_hasher> edges; // <- hasher included

public:
    Graph() = default;
    ~Graph();
}
```